# RazorEngine TemplateServiceConfiguration is not compatible with log4net LogicalThreadStack

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net, razorengine

Since xUnit executes multiple threads parallel it is necessary to use the `LogicalThreadContext` from log4net to retrieve only the messages pertaining to the current test (any ideas of other methods of doing this are welcome).

Normally I have no problems with this setup but. Today I changed a test that uses RazorEngine to also use the solution below (before I filtered by the thread name an ID). It doesn't work anymore. Testing showed that the Problem is with the instantiation of the `TemplateServiceConfiguration`.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Normally this works:

```
    var mapp = new MemoryAppender();
    BasicConfigurator.Configure(mapp);

    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("moduleX");
    using (log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["TestStack"].Push("context"))
    {
        logger.Warn("Something happened!");

        mapp.GetEvents().Where(x => (string)x.Properties["TestStack"] == "context").ToList().Count.ShouldBe(1);
    }
```

But as soon as I introduce a TemplateServiceConfiguration it does not:

```
    var mapp = new MemoryAppender();
    BasicConfigurator.Configure(mapp);

    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("moduleX");
    using (log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["TestStack"].Push("context"))
    {
        logger.Warn("Something happened!");

        var tsc = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();

        logger.Warn("More happenings!");

        // assert now fails
        mapp.GetEvents().Where(x => (string)x.Properties["TestStack"] == "context").ToList().Count.ShouldBe(2);
    }
```

**Update**

The events are still there but the `Properties` property no longer contains the `TestStack` entry.

**End update**

Here is the constructor code for [TemplateServiceConfiguration](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/311c3bbd752cab910d35676ca51f9c5e0780c354/src/source/RazorEngine.Core/Configuration/TemplateServiceConfiguration.cs)

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public TemplateServiceConfiguration()
    {
        Activator = new DefaultActivator();
        CompilerServiceFactory =
    #if RAZOR4
          new Roslyn.RoslynCompilerServiceFactory();
    #else
            new DefaultCompilerServiceFactory();
    #endif
        EncodedStringFactory = new HtmlEncodedStringFactory();

    #if !RAZOR4
    #pragma warning disable 0618 // Backwards Compat.
        CodeInspectors = new List<ICodeInspector>();
    #pragma warning restore 0618 // Backwards Compat.
    #endif

        ReferenceResolver = new UseCurrentAssembliesReferenceResolver();
        CachingProvider = new DefaultCachingProvider();
        TemplateManager =
            new DelegateTemplateManager();

        Namespaces = new HashSet<string>
                         {
                             "System", 
                             "System.Collections.Generic", 
                             "System.Linq"
                         };

        var config = RazorEngineConfigurationSection.GetConfiguration();
        Language = (config == null)
                       ? Language.CSharp
                       : config.DefaultLanguage;
    }
```

Comment: `It does not work` means what? any exception?

Comment: @Nkosi Sorry I thought that was clear from the second example. The commant stating `// assert now fails`. I have updated the question.